# Convert rows to column in Oracle with static column header

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to convert below data set into columns, any help in SQL for this.

Data Set

| col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1 |
| A | 2 |
| A | 3 |
| A | 4 |
| A | 5 |

Converted Data Set

| col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 | col5 | col6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |

Answer (score 0):

You can `PIVOT`:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   data_set
PIVOT(
  MAX(col2) FOR col2 IN (
    1 AS col2,
    2 AS col3,
    3 AS col4,
    4 AS col5,
    5 AS col6
  )
)
```

Or, use conditional aggregation:

```sql
SELECT col1,
       MAX(CASE col2 WHEN 1 THEN col2 END) AS col2,
       MAX(CASE col2 WHEN 2 THEN col2 END) AS col3,
       MAX(CASE col2 WHEN 3 THEN col2 END) AS col4,
       MAX(CASE col2 WHEN 4 THEN col2 END) AS col5,
       MAX(CASE col2 WHEN 5 THEN col2 END) AS col6
FROM   data_set
GROUP BY col1
```

Which, for your sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE data_set (col1, col2) AS
SELECT 'A', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', 4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', 5 FROM DUAL;
```

Both output:

> | COL1 | COL2 | COL3 | COL4 | COL5 | COL6 |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | A | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=6dbbd8490474645470cb8effdba0897e)*